# Gradle Copy task doesn't work with doFirst / doLast

Tags: gradle

I have a simple copy task that is successfully copying files, but not executing the doFirst/doLast items configured for the task.

Here's the code (build.gradle):

```
task x(type: Copy) {
  copy {
    from(projectDir) {
      include 'build.gradle'
    }
    into(buildDir)
  }
  println "Configuring."
  doFirst {
    println "Inside doFirst."
  }
  doLast {
    println "Inside doLast."
  }
}
```

Simple enough: The single task 'x' copies the build.gradle script itself - the sole file in the project folder - into the project's build folder.

Here's execution, first ensuring there is no prior output and showing that there is an output after execution:

```
c:\jdev\newpaas\gradlebug>rd /s /q build & gradle x & dir build
The system cannot find the file specified.

> Configure project :
Configuring.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 22A1-4AC1

 Directory of c:\jdev\newpaas\gradlebug\build

01/05/2022  07:44 PM    <DIR>          .
01/05/2022  07:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/05/2022  07:44 PM               277 build.gradle
               1 File(s)            277 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  31,110,651,904 bytes free
```

First, the build folder was not present - hence it could not be deleted.

Gradle is showing the message in the configuration phase.  But the "dofirst" and "doLast" messages are not shown.

After execution, the build folder does exist and is properly populated with a copy of the build script, suggesting that the 'x' task did in fact execute.  But the messages in doFirst and doLast did not print.

There are similar questions on StackOverflow and elsewhere, but the examples I've seen have been flawed in that the code shown in those questions has shown no inputs or outputs - just doFirst and doLast - and so the answer has been that the task is already up to date and that is why it is not executing; or that the entire body of the task is preceded by '<<' and is therefore an empty task with a doLast block.  **This** is an example of a Copy task that **is** configured, **is ** demonstrably executing, just not running its doFirst and doLast closures.

I am running Gradle 7.3 on Windows 10.

My need is not to print messages, but I have discovered that a project plugin's post-task configuration is not executing in Copy tasks, and it appears to boil down to this issue.  I have tried using 'into('') (path to file, instead of path to folder with includes), and adding an outputs.upToDateWhen { false } entry in the task definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to call copy again inside your custom task. try below

```
task x(type: Copy) {
    from(projectDir) {
        include 'build.gradle'
    }
    into(buildDir)
    println "Configuring " + projectDir
    doFirst {
        println "Inside doFirst."
    }
    doLast {
        println "Inside doLast."
    }
}
```

Comment: *Sigh*  Sometimes you can't see the forest for the trees.  I knew that.  Thank you for your response.