doFirst and doLast not executed in Gradle Copy command
I use to have this sample gradle task (to demo doFirst and doAfter) that works

task copyFile(type: Copy) {
    group 'elye'
    description 'Copy Only"'
    from 'source'
    into 'destination'
    doFirst {
        println "Before Copy"
        exec {
         commandLine 'sleep', '10'
        }
    }
    doLast {
        println "After Copy"
    }
}

But recently when I run it, it doesn't work anymore (i.e. it don't print out the log, and don't wait 10 seconds).
I need to change to a new code below that works. But it is not what I want as it don't help show the use of doFirst and doLast handle separately from the actual task
task copyFile {
    group 'elye'
    description 'Copy Only'
    doFirst {
        println "Before Copy"
        println "Copying files..."
        exec {
            commandLine 'sleep', '10'
        }
        copy {
            from 'source'
            into 'destination'
        }
    }
    doLast {
        println "After Copy"
        println "Files copied successfully."
    }
}

Why wasn't my former gradle script working anymore?

Looks like I need to have a script that works with actual copy
task copyFile(type: Copy) {
    group 'elye'
    description 'Copy Only"'

    def source = projectDir
    def destination = buildDir

    from source
    into destination
    
    println "Configuring " + projectDir
    doFirst {
        println "Before Copy"
        exec {
         commandLine 'sleep', '10'
        }
    }
    doLast {
        println "After Copy"
    }
}

Learned the solution partly from https://stackoverflow.com/a/70603330/3286489
